# How to Use IF Exist condition

Tags: windows, batch-file

i have a batch script to check the status of a task running by the task scheduler and the status of the batch file and also the status of the Network load balancer.

my question is :-

step-1:- I want to check the status of task(health.bat) running in task scheduler if it is enabled or in ready status then jump and check the step-2

step-2:- here i need to check the status of network load balancer(NLB) if it is in converged state then jump and exit or else run -->health.bat-->if there is no error --> start the NLB or else-->send the mail with the error message

**Issue with this code:-**

The code is running up to call health.bat then it jumps to start the NLB even though the health.bat fails :-

```
  @echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set itemail="mailid"
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET host=%%i
::set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
set TASKNAME1=health
c:
cd\
cd batch
:: Checking is wscheck is disabled
schtasks.exe /query  /tn "%TASKNAME1%" >CheckTS.txt 2>&1  
findstr "Running Ready" CheckTS.txt
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 ( 
schtasks.exe /change /ENABLE /TN "%TASKNAME1%" >CheckTS.txt
schtasks.exe /query  /tn "%TASKNAME1%" >>CheckTS.txt
wmailto %itemail% -s"The Task health has been enabled on %host%." -tCheckTS.txt
)
:: Checking if the node is stared
NLB.exe query >CheckNLB.txt 2>&1
findstr /L /c:"converged" CheckNLB.txt
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
call wscheck.bat
IF EXIST findstr /L /c:"<--FAIL-->" health.txt ( 
wmailto %itemail% -s"DOWN The node %host% cannot be started as the health failed." -thealthstatus.txt
goto :exit
) ELSE (
NLB.exe start >CheckNLB.txt
TIMEOUT /T 10
NLB.exe query >>CheckNLB.txt
wmailto %itemail% -s"The NLB has been Started on %host%." -tCheckNLB.txt
)
)


:exit
pause
```

--->health.bat<---

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
REM set 
set itemail= "mailid"

pushd "c:\health" || goto :eof

    set "tries=2"
    for /l %%a in (1 1 %tries%) do (
      >health.txt (
            call pcheck.cmd
            Tester.exe -s parse 
        )
        echo The Tester returned errorlevel : !errorlevel! 
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            wmailto %itemail% -s"UP -  Health Monitoring." -thealth.txt"
            goto :eof
        )
        if %%a equ %tries% (
           wmailto %itemail% -s"DOWN -  Health Monitoring." -thealth.txt

        )
    )
```

Comment: If you use the `variable` errorlevel inside a (code block) you need [delayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion) to get the actual value not the one at parse time when entering the code block.

Comment: What do you have in `healt.bat` ? Does it change the errorlevel?Instead of `if %errorlevel% NEQ 0` try `if not errorlevel 0` or use delyaed expansion as LotPings suggested.

Comment: i enabled the delayedexpansion but it is not executing the NLB.exe Start it is directly going to exit eventhought the health.bat pass,

Comment: i have t percentage calculation of the CPU and Memory usage and checking one internal tool  in health.bat and yes it will change the errorlevel, i tired if not errorlevel 0 but it is directly going to exit after it execute the first IF statement .

Comment: added the code of health.bat @npocmaka

Comment: if i use if not errorlevel 0, NLB.exe Start is executing eventhough the health.bat is failed